# Amplpy: How to use output handler?

Tags: python, output, ampl, amplpy

I am new in AMPL and Python and I am using amplpy to run an AMPL model, using lpopt solver.
I need to get the output result of the solver in a way that I can act over it, i.e. I need to know if the optimal solution was found to decide if I can use the variables' final values or not; for lpopt, in the middle of all other outputs, it prints automatically "EXIT: Optimal Solution Found".
I tried using the get_output_handler and OutputHandler classes, but I could not find a proper example on how it works and how to actually implement it.
My idea is to get the "EXIT: ..." sentence and decide whether to save the variables' results or not, conceptually, it would look something like this:

```
'''
output_sentence = ampl.OutputHandler(...)
if output_sentence == "EXIT: Optimal Solution Found":
     x = ampl.get_variable("x").get_values()
else:
     x = nan
'''
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an output handler, the easiest way to obtain the output from the solver would be to use the following:

```py
solve_output = ampl.get_output("solve;")
if "EXIT: Optimal Solution Found" in solve_output:
     x = ampl.get_variable("x").get_values()
else:
     x = None
```

However, you can also achieve what you need by simply checking the solve_result with `ampl.get_value("solve_result")` as follows:

```py
ampl.solve()
solve_result = ampl.get_value("solve_result")
if solve_result == "solved":
    x = ampl.get_variable("x").get_values()
else:
    x = None
```

This later option would work for other solvers, while the first one only applied to Ipopt since it checks for specific output.